# DataBase open in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm trying to connect the database from my VS C++ app but when it's get to line when open DateBase I have error and message :

KeyNotFoundException

I don't know whay I do wrong

I have done some change and when I put "SELECT actor_id FROM sakila.actor" give me  result
but when try select all by '*' I get error

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        String^ config = L"datasource=localhost;port = 3306; username=root;password=1234; ";
        MySqlConnection^ ConnDB = gcnew MySqlConnection(config);
        MySqlCommand^ order = gcnew MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sakila.city;", ConnDB);
        MySqlDataReader^ openDB;

        try
        {
        ConnDB->Open();

            openDB = order->ExecuteReader();
            while (openDB->Read())
            {
            txtWynik->Text += (openDB->GetInt16(0)) + "\r\n";

            }
        }
             catch (Exception^ komunikat)
    {
        MessageBox::Show(komunikat->Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure [that's the function you wanted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint16?view=netframework-4.7.2)? Is "city" really a signed 16-bit integer?

Comment: i try with actor as well and change to GetInt32 and GetString still smae problem

Comment: Shouldn't it be "SELECT city FROM sakila"?

Comment: sakila.city is MySql command need be used